# Fraunhofer limit in infinitely long slit

Tags: optics, diffraction

In the optics book by Ajoy Ghatak, the Fresnel integral was approximated to be $$u(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{i\lambda z} e^{ikz}e^{ik(\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2z})} \iint A(\epsilon,\eta) e^{\frac{ik}{2z}(\eta^{2}+\epsilon^{2})} e^{-i(w\epsilon +v\eta )} d\epsilon d\eta$$
where $w = \frac{2\pi x}{\lambda z} v = \frac{2\pi y}{\lambda z}$, 
$\epsilon \eta$ plane (z=0 plane) is the aperture plane and $xy$ plane (z = z) plane is the image plane. $u(x,y,z)$ is the field at image plane under the approximation $$z\gg\frac{((x-\epsilon)^2+(y+\eta)^2)^{2/3}}{(4\lambda)^{1/3}}$$ further taking Fraunhofer approximation ie,$$z\gg\frac{[\epsilon^2+\eta^2]_{max}}{\lambda}$$ we could reduce the above integral to $$u(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{i\lambda z} e^{ikz}e^{ik(\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{2z})} \iint A(\epsilon,\eta) e^{-i(w\epsilon +v\eta )} d\epsilon d\eta$$
The author uses this reduced integral to find diffraction pattern by an aperture of width $b$ along the $\epsilon$ direction and elongated to infinity in the $\eta $ direction. How can the second approximation hold in such a scenario?

Comment: either the illumination is localized in $\epsilon$ and $\eta$ or if it is uniform in $\eta$ then that variable is to be ignored to reduce to a 1-d Fourier transform.

Comment: if the illumination is localised ie, $\epsilon,\eta$ are small enough then the integral holds . I don't understand how it can be so when uniformly illuminated along $\eta$ ? @hyportnex

Comment: as i said above if it is really uniform then the formula does not work, then you will have a 1-d transform.